# An array of structs defined in other source file

Tags: c, sockets, struct, tcp

For a school project i made this program where clients (a tcpsock_t) can make a TCP connection with a server and pass data through it. I poll the different connections to see if there is data to read.

I got a tcpsock.c with functions for the TCP sockets which is used as library, a connmgr.c as server and a client code (which is not relevant).

In the tcpsock.h i typedef the struct of the tcpsock_t
(other functions below)

```
typedef struct tcpsock tcpsock_t;
```

and in the tcpsock.c i declare the struct (and it should stay here, i can not put it in de .h file)

```
struct tcpsock{
 long cookie;
 int sd;
 char * ip_addr;
 int port;
 };
```

In the connmgr.c i want to make an array of this tcpsock_t to store all my connected clients, but when i compile it gives always the same sort of errors:

> error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct tcpsock’
>        client[conn_counter] = *requestclient;

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Here is my server code :

```
#include "tcpsock.h" 
#include "connmgr.h"       
int conn_counter = 0;

    void add_client(tcpsock_t *newclient, tcpsock_t * array){
        conn_counter++;
        array= realloc(test,sizeof(get_size_tcpsock())*conn_counter);
        array[conn_counter-1]=*newclient; //here i have the error

    }

    void add_poll(struct pollfd * polllist, tcpsock_t *client, tcpsock_t *server){
        polllist = realloc(polllist,sizeof(struct pollfd)*conn_counter+1);
        int clientsd;
        tcp_get_sd(server, &clientsd);
        polllist[conn_counter].fd= clientsd;
        polllist[conn_counter].events = POLLIN;

    }


    int main(void){

        tcpsock_t *server;
        tcpsock_t *client;
        client = malloc(sizeof(get_size_tcpsock()));
        struct pollfd *poll_list;
        poll_list = malloc(sizeof(struct pollfd));
        sensor_data_t data;

        int bytes,result;

        if(tcp_passive_open(&server,PORT)!=TCP_NO_ERROR)exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        int serversd;
        tcp_get_sd(server, &serversd);
        poll_list[0].fd = serversd;
        poll_list[0].events = POLLIN;

        printf("start polling \n");

        while(1){

            int retval,i;
            retval = poll(poll_list,conn_counter+1,5000);
            if (retval>0){
                if(poll_list[0].revents && POLLIN>0){
                    tcpsock_t *requestclient;
                    tcp_wait_for_connection(server,&requestclient);
                client[conn_counter] = *requestclient; //here i have the error
                    add_client(requestclient,client);
                    add_poll(poll_list, requestclient, server);

                }
                for (i=0; i<conn_counter+1;i++){
                    if(poll_list[i+1].revents & POLLIN){

                        bytes = sizeof(data.id);
                        result = tcp_receive(client[i],(void *)&data.id,&bytes); //here i have the error

                        bytes = sizeof(data.value);
                        result = tcp_receive(client[i],(void *)&data.value,&bytes); //here i have the error

                        bytes = sizeof(data.ts);
                        result =tcp_receive(client[i],(void *)&data.ts,&bytes); //here i have the error
                        if ((result==TCP_NO_ERROR) && bytes){

                            printf("sensor id = %" PRIu16 " - temperature = %g - timestamp = %ld\n", data.id, data.value, (long int)data.ts);

                                }

                        fflush(stdout);
                    }
                    if (poll_list[i+1].revents & POLLHUP){
                        printf("client disconnected \n");
                        poll_list[conn_counter+1].fd=-1;
                        poll_list[conn_counter+1].events=0;
                        fflush(stdout);
                    }
                }       
            }

        }



        tcp_close(&server);
        return 1;
    }
```

Here is the tcpsock.h, but the functions work fine.

```
typedef struct tcpsock tcpsock_t;

int get_size_tcpsock();

int tcp_passive_open(tcpsock_t ** socket, int port);
/* Creates a new socket and opens this socket in 'passive listening mode' (waiting for an active connection setup request) 
 * The socket is bound to port number 'port' and to any active IP interface of the system
 */

int tcp_active_open(tcpsock_t ** socket, int remote_port, char * remote_ip);
/* Creates a new TCP socket and opens a TCP connection to the system with IP address 'remote_ip' on port 'remote_port'
 * The newly created socket is return as '*socket'
 */

int tcp_close(tcpsock_t ** socket); 

int tcp_wait_for_connection(tcpsock_t * socket, tcpsock_t ** new_socket); 
/* Puts the socket 'socket' in a blocking wait mode
 * Returns when an incoming TCP connection setup request is received
 * A newly created socket identifying the remote system that initiated the connection request is returned as '*new_socket'
 */

int tcp_send(tcpsock_t * socket, void * buffer, int * buf_size );
/* Initiates a send command on the socket 'socket' and tries to send the total '*buf_size' bytes of data in 'buffer' (recall that the function might block for a while)
 * The function sets '*buf_size' to the number of bytes that were really sent, which might be less than the initial '*buf_size'
 */

int tcp_get_ip_addr( tcpsock_t * socket, char ** ip_addr);
/* Set '*ip_addr' to the IP address of 'socket' (could be NULL if the IP address is not set)
 */

int tcp_get_port(tcpsock_t * socket, int * port); 

int tcp_get_sd(tcpsock_t * socket, int * sd);
```

Comment: "i can not put it in de .h file". Well that is the exact problem. `connmgr.c` needs to know the full definition of `struct tcpsock`. If it is not in a header file that it includes then it needs to be in the C file itself (the latter is a bad idea as it would have the struct defn in two places). Does `connmgr` need to access the internals of the struct? If it does then you can't arrange the code as you have it now. If it doesn't then the array should store pointers to the struct rather than the structs themselves (it is ok to declare pointers to incomplete types).

Comment: No, the connmgr can not have access to the internals, that's why it is in the tcpsock.c . Okay I see what you mean, and how do i exactly store these pointers in code?

Comment: `tcpsock_t **client; client = malloc(MAX_CLIENTS * sizeof(tcpsock_t *)); client[conn_counter] = requestclient;`

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed it!